# Java/Kotlin annotation processor: get type of annotated field/property

Tags: java, annotations, kotlin

For example I have a class:

```
class Foo {
  @AnnotatedProp
  var foo: Boolean? = null
}
```

How can I get type of `foo` property in my custom annotation processor?
in pseudo I'd expect something like:
`annotatedElement.getStringifiedReturnTypeSomehow() //returns "Boolean"`

Answer (score 3):

The way I've done it, ensure your annotation has an `AnnotationTarget.FIELD` target.

Than after you get the `Element` instance with required annotation, just:
`val returnTypeQualifiedName = element.asType().toString()` 
if you want to find out if it's nullable:

```
private fun isNullableProperty(element: Element): Boolean {
        val nullableAnnotation = element.getAnnotation(org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable::class.java)
        if (nullableAnnotation == null) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: element.asType() 
In Kotlin returns null as ```getFoo$annotations()``` does return void from the decompiled code. Not sure if this still works Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score -4):

You can use reflection to get what you need.

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties
import kotlin.reflect.full.findAnnotation
import kotlin.reflect.full.starProjectedType

annotation class AnnotatedProp

class Foo {
    @AnnotatedProp
    var foo: Boolean? = null
    var bar: String? = null
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // Process annotated properties declared in class Foo.
    Foo::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter {
        it.findAnnotation<AnnotatedProp>() != null
    }.forEach {
        println("Name: ${it.name}")
        println("Nullable: ${it.returnType.isMarkedNullable}")
        println("Type: ${it.returnType.classifier!!.starProjectedType}")
    }

}
```

This will print out:

```
Name: foo
Nullable: true
Type: kotlin.Boolean
```

Kotlin's standard library does not come with reflection, so be sure to add

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$version_kotlin"
```

to your Gradle build file.

Comment: he asked about annotation processors, not a normal function