# Annotation processor in Kotlin: nullable types

Tags: annotations, kotlin, annotation-processing

I'm writting my first annotation processor in Kotlin. I need to check the type of a annotated property in order to know if is optional or not.

The client code looks like:

```
 @MyAnnotation var property: String?
```

In my annotation processor, I have an instance of Element class from javax.lang.model.element packpage which represents my annotated property. I can do element.asType() to get the type the property, but I don't know how to check if this property is optional or not.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323988/java-kotlin-annotation-processor-get-type-of-annotated-field-property